# store a mixture of ASP VBScript and HTML in a database

Tags: asp-classic

I'm attempting to get rid of an app's HTML files and store their contents in a database. The thing is, there's a mixture of classic ASP/VBscript code and HTML within those files.

So for example, as well as regular HTML there are things like:

```
Your name is <%=sYourName%>
```

and

```
<% If .... Then %>
<p>blah blah blah</p>
<% End If %>
```

When this gets pulled from the DB and output to the browser, the ASP/VBScript code isn't parsed so it's displayed as regular text.

So my question is, is there a way to store this ASP/HTML mixture in a DB and get the correct output to the browser?

Thanks!

Comment: How are you pulling the data out of the database to send back to the browser? Normally people use ASP to query the DB data and build the HTML

Comment: ASP is used to pull the data from the DB, calling stored procedures directly. The 'data' part (i.e. the dynamic stuff) is XML, transformed using XSL into a variable. These variables are then output in the HTML like in the example above.

Comment: I would recommend you review the idea tha XSL generates ASP (note "the example above" is __not__ HTML its ASP). Bring the scripting aspect into the XSL there are many options available to help with that.  XSL's own (but limited) "flow control", MSXML allow script code such as VBScript to be embedded in XSL to provide functions that do more complex things.  MSXML also allows external namespaces to reference functiosn defined externally to the XSL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all let me caveat with **don't do this**.

ASP requires a file from which to process an ASP script, there is no way to read text from a DB then execute it as an ASP script directly.

However you could read text from the DB and write it to a temporary file under your website's physical folder then user `Server.Execute` to run it.  (**EDIT** or in reference to your clarification in the question comments you could have XSL output to a file and the server execute that file).

That said this seems an insane thing to do.  The exposure to malicious use itself makes it unwise to start with.  I'm also unsure of what advantage this provides over just having physical files to start with.

Comment: +1 I concur with Anthony that this seems a rather odd thing to do, dont get me wrong, your serving asp page could parse the asp from SQL using methods such as eval() & Execute() but you might as well just bend over and wave security goodbye - Only reason i can think of doing this is some kind of CMS? (i.e. the open source CMS phpfusion allows php to be stored in a database, but only admins have access to change this information - still, a very risky thing to do if you dont 100% trust all your admins / content authors).

Comment: @HeavenCore:  Eval and Execute will only work on pure VBScript, you can't use them on code that contains HTML content as well.

Comment: Thanks Anthony - that's pretty much what I was expecting based on what I've read, but wondered if there was another option I hadn't found (that's secure and doesn't involve writing to temp files).